# Mathematica: Excel imported list parameters not working on piecewise function

Tags: excel, list, wolfram-mathematica, piecewise

I have a piecewise function like:

```
q1N := (e + w)/(e + b)

FeasR := Piecewise[{{1, q1N <= q}, {0, q < q1N}}]
```

parameters e,w and b are imported from Excel using this code:

```
InData := Import["C:\\Users\\HR\\Desktop\\DatImp.csv"]
MainData := InData[[2 ;; 1001, 2 ;; 7]]

b := MainData[[All, 1]]
w := MainData[[All, 2]]
e := MainData[[All, 3]]
q := MainData[[All, 4]]
```

b,e,q and w shape different cases where FeasR would determine feasibility based on comparison of q1N and q.

The problem is that FeasR output is not in the form of {{1,0,1,1,0,...}}.

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In this example `InData` is random so the output will differ.

```
InData = RandomReal[10, {10, 7}];
MainData = InData[[2 ;; 10, 2 ;; 7]];
b = MainData[[All, 1]]
w = MainData[[All, 2]]
e = MainData[[All, 3]]
q = MainData[[All, 4]]

q1N := (e + w)/(e + b)

FeasR = Piecewise[{{1, Thread[q1N <= q]}, {0, Thread[q < q1N]}}]
```

> ```
> { 1   {True,True,False,True,True,True,True,True,True}
> { 0   True
> ```

However, this is not the format you want.  Use `Boole` instead.

```
FeasR = Boole[Thread[q1N <= q]]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris!

I realized turning FeasR into a function would work as well:

FeasR[b_, w_, e_, a_, q_, d_] = 
 Piecewise[{{1, q1N <= q}, {0, q < q1N}}]

The only thing to consider is to follow the order of parameters (b,w,e,a,q and d) in the CSV file. 

Then I can use:

Apply[FeasR]/@InData

and have the results for all the cases.


Thanks very much! Cheers!